# How to create a multiline string variable in swig template?

Tags: node.js, swig-template

I'm trying to create a multiline string variable in swig :

```
{% set myVariable = "
  multi
  line
  string
" %}
```

Then I log it :

```
{% logMyVariable(myVariable) %}
```

But I don't understand why my variable is not displayed on several lines :

```
multi line string
```

Whereas I was expecting :

```
multi
line 
string
```

Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: Outputting to HTML? Ever heard of `<br>`?

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, new lines in text aren’t rendered when the text is displayed. For example, this HTML:

```
<p>Let’s split this sentence up
onto
multiple
lines.</p>
```

Will render like this:

```
Let’s split this sentence up onto multiple lines.
```

You might want to wrap your `log` in a [`<pre>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre), as that will preserve new lines (and multiple spaces between words, which are also ignored in rendered HTML):

```
<pre>{% logMyVariable(myVariable) %}</pre>
```